# WSO2 ESB - NullPointerException while sending IDOC to SAP

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

**Facing the following error while sending the IDOC to SAP.
Transport configurations are fine (Even BAPI message to SAP is successful)**

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.SAPTransportSender} - Error
>   while sending an IDoc to the EPR : idoc:/sapdelts
>   {org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.SAPTransportSender}
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.idoc.DefaultIDocXMLMapper.closeStream(DefaultIDocXMLMapper.java:68)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.idoc.DefaultIDocXMLMapper.getDocumentList(DefaultIDocXMLMapper.java:59)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.SAPTransportSender.getIDocs(SAPTransportSender.java:163)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.SAPTransportSender.sendMessage(SAPTransportSender.java:103)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
>   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442) at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:185)
>   at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:167)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)

When the following error handlers were enabled, receive the below error message along with the previous error stack trace (above)

```
<parameter name="transport.sap.enableTIDHandler">enabled</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.sap.enableErrorListener">enabled</parameter>
```

{org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - ERROR_CODE : 8001 {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}

WARN
{org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - ERROR_MESSAGE : null {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}

WARN
{org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - ERROR_DETAIL : null {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}

WARN
{org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - ERROR_EXCEPTION : null {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}

WARN
{org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - FaultHandler : Endpoint [sapidocendpoint] {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}

Answer (score 0):

I faced several issues with the SAP transport when sending IDOCs. Which version of ESB are you using? Can you please post your configuration or the IDOC that is send to SAP transport.